# What are the better algorithms to find the influencing factors in data mining

Tags: dataset, data-mining, rapidminer

I am working on a dataset of student activities and I want to understand what are the factors affecting their grades while they study and I would like to know which algorithm will yield me good results. As I tried the FP growth algorithm to get the rules... but are there any other algorithms that could work well for me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What about regression?s

That would be the standard technique here. Build a regression model and then interpret the factors.